# JavaアプリケーションにおいてOS環境変数のデフォルト値を設定する方法

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-boot

既存のサードパーティライブラリでOS環境変数（System.getenv()で取得できる値）を使用しているロジックがあります。
しかし、当該ライブラリを使用したEclipseプロジェクトをセットアップする度に デバッグの構成 > 環境 で変数を追加するのが（１つずつ変数を追加しなければいけない為）面倒です。

環境変数のデフォルト値を設定する手段などはないでしょうか。
開発環境：Eclipse
開発言語：Java
フレームワーク：Spring Boot

application.properties に設定することで実現できないかと推測したのですが、うまくできていません。
なにか情報をお持ちの方はご教示頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一番簡単なのは Eclipse プラグインを使うことでしょうか。
http://jorisaerts.github.io/Eclipse-Environment-Variables/

後は、OS の種類によって（`.bashrc` を使うなど）色々やり方が違うと思いますが、どの OS でも使えそうなのは、Eclipse の起動シェル（macOS なら `Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse`）に直接環境変数を宣言しておく方法が、汚いけれど確実です。

```
#!/bin/sh

export MY_ENV1=my-value1
export MY_ENV2=my-value2
```

Comment: なるほど、プラグインはいいですね。ただ、ベストなのはまっさらなPCにEclipseをインストールして、プロジェクトをCloneしたら開発が始められるような形にしたいんですよね...追加のプラグインを入れたり、定義ファイルをデプロイしたり、なんだか新規参画してきたメンバに教えることがいっぱいなんですよね...